# Is it possible to change the wicket output?

Tags: html, components, wicket

*Hello,
I am wondering if it is possible to change the wicket output html code. e.g. for the component "CheckBoxMultipleChoice" you will get the following html output.*

```
<span wicket:id="letters">
<input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="0" id="letters_0"/><label for="letters_0">fff</label><br/>
<input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="1" id="letters_1"/><label for="letters_1">aaa</label><br/>
<input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="2" id="letters_2"/><label for="letters_2">bbb</label><br/>
<input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="3" id="letters_3"/><label for="letters_3">ccc</label><br/>
<input name="letters" type="checkbox" value="4" id="letters_4"/><label for="letters_4">ddd</label><br/>
</span>
```

*if i dont want the `<br/>` tag, what can i do?
regards*

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the component.

For anything `Panel`-based, you can always subclass the component (`MyPanel.java`) and supply a different markup file (`MyPanel.html`). As long as you have the same `wicket:id`s in there, it works fine.

For built-in Wicket components that have markup elements embedded in their source code, like `CheckBoxMultipleChoice`, you're at the mercy of the custom API of the component. In your case it looks like you want [CheckBoxMultipleChoice#setSuffix](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/CheckBoxMultipleChoice.html#setSuffix%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 4):

No, extract from the [documentation](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html)

> Components may alter their referring tag, replace the tag's body or insert markup after the tag. But components cannot remove tags from the markup stream. This is an important guarantee because graphic designers may be setting attributes on component tags that affect visual presentation.

however if you want add/remove new line spaces between your components you can change the display of component to block/inline

```
@Override
protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
    super.onComponentTag(tag);
    //block or inline 
    tag.put("style", "display:block");
}
```

or use a CSS class